# Why do I get an error when applying getInfo() in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, cloud-cover

I'm working in an undergraduate project and just started using Google Earth Engine. Firstly, I need to filter some Sentinel-2 MSI images that cover my area of interest (a watershed with 55 km²) from 2016 to 2022 (the idea is to get one image per month).
So far, I've applied several filters. I noticed that the QA60 band for the 2022 images is not working properly, so I decided to use the Cloud Probability collection for analysing cloud coverage.
After applying the function `get_cloud_percent()`, which I created to analyze the cloud band within my area of interest and add the information to the metadata, I got unable to get the metadata as a list using `my_dataset.getInfo()`. It works just fine before the application of `get_cloud_percent()`. But the execution of the last line of the code bellow returns the following error: `EEException: computation timed out`.
Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?
I've coded in Python, as follows:

```
# %% SHAPEFILE UPLOAD

# Uploading the shapefile
lc_shape = gpd.read_file('lc_bh/bacia_LC.shp')
print(f'\nShapefile CRS is {lc_shape.crs}')

# Conversion of CRS to WGS84
lc_shape = lc_shape.to_crs(epsg=4326)
print(f'\nShapefile CRS converted to {lc_shape.crs}')

# Selection of the feature of interest
lc_shape = lc_shape.geometry[0][2]

# Extraction of the contours
# Coordinates are generated in pairs
lc_ext_coords = lc_shape.exterior.coords

# A tuple is generated to store a list of latitudes and a list of longitudes
lc_ext_coords = lc_ext_coords.xy

# Coordinates grouped in pairs (each pair latlong forms a list)
lc_ext_coords = np.dstack(lc_ext_coords).tolist()

# Creation of a ee.Feature with the external coordinates
lc_geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(lc_ext_coords)

# %% UPLOADING OF SENTINEL-2 DATA

# Initial and final dates
DATE_I, DATE_F = '2016-01-01', '2022-03-31'

# Sentinel 2 Harmonized data
# Filter: by date
# Filter: by bounds (select the images that touch the geometry)
dataset_1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')\
    .filterDate(DATE_I, DATE_F).filterBounds(lc_geometry)

# %% FILTERING BY IMAGE EXTENT AND QUALITY

# Filter: images must contain the area of interest
dataset_2 = dataset_1.filter(ee.Filter.contains('.geo', lc_geometry))

# Filter: the images must have a proper general quality
dataset_3 = dataset_2.filter(
    ee.Filter.Or(ee.Filter.eq('GENERAL_QUALITY', 'PASSED'),
                 ee.Filter.eq('GENERAL_QUALITY_FLAG', 'PASSED')))

# %% INCLUSION OF CLOUD PROBABILITY BAND

# Cloud Probability data
cloud_prob_data = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')\
    .filterDate(DATE_I, DATE_F).filterBounds(lc_geometry)

# The cloud probability band is added to the image dataset considering
# metadata matches
dataset_4 = dataset_3.combine(cloud_prob_data)

# %% CLOUD MASK ANALYSIS

# Function used on the processing
# Used because the values are quite low
def scale_dict(key, value):

    """
    This function takes an ee.Dictionary and multiply its values
    by a factor of 1e4 and rounds it to the nearest integer
    """

    return ee.Number(value).multiply(1e4).round()


# Function to be mapped over the collection
def get_cloud_percent(image):

    """
    This function calculates the cloud cover proportion at the geometry and
    adds it to the metadata as a new attribute called cloudiness, whose values
    are multiplied by a factor of 1e4
    """

    # Selection of cloud probability band
    # Clouds assumed as pixels with probability >= 70%
    # It is assigned 1 to the selected pixels and 0 to the others
    cloud_band = image.select(['probability']).gte(70)

    # Generation of cloud proportion
    # Since the values are just 0 e 1, the mean is equal to the proportion
    # A ee.Dictionary is generated with a key renamed to "cloudiness"
    # The proportion (not the percentage) is multiplied by 1e4 and rounded
    cloud_percent = cloud_band.reduceRegion(**{
        'reducer':ee.Reducer.mean(),
        'geometry':lc_geometry,
        'scale':10}).rename(['probability'], ['CLOUDINESS'], True)\
        .map(scale_dict)

    # Information added to metadata
    return image.set(cloud_percent)


# Function mapped over the collection
# Filter: election of images with cloudiness <= 1% (0.01x1e4)
dataset_5 = dataset_4.map(get_cloud_percent)\
    .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDINESS', 0.01*1e4))

# Get list of metadata
info_list = dataset_5.getInfo()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getInfo` you are using the "interactive" processing environment, which is intended for small requests that finish quickly ([learn more here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#interactive-environment)). If you do `dataset_5.limit(5).getInfo()` it should work (limit to small amount for checking). What do you intend to do with all the metadata? Maybe consider using `ee.ImageCollection.reduceColumns` and `ee.ImageCollection.aggregate_*` functions to summarize the metadata.

Comment: I was doing some filtering using the metadata in Pandas Dataframe format. But I reduced a lot of code by filtering it with the proper GEE functions. However, now I need to select a single image per month, and I'm not sure about how to do it without using loops over a dataframe. This is the reason I'd like the metadata (some specific attributes). If I use `ee.ImageCollection.reduceColumns`, I also can't use `getInfo()` to get a Python list (i.e., a list I can read). In this case, should I export the metadata or there is something equivalent to `getInfo()` I could use to save it as a list?

Answer (score 0):

The "calculation timed out" is because you are processing many images in addition to calculating the percentage of clouds in each one.

Try to use [this code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/390b72492516d74592206acdb6c8badd) to select only one image per month with COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY. It works for up to 6 months due to the number of images that exist, but it will depend on your area.

BTW the shadows of the clouds are seen in the image.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding Questions without code get closed, and coding Answers without code get deleted (since all links fail over time, link-only answers are flagged for deletion). Please place the relevant code block within the body of your answer.